# How to do a nested loop Jupyter Notebook Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gurobi

I am starting to work with Jupyter Notebook and I have no idea how to do a nested loop, tried everything I could think of. What I want to do is:

```
I=(0,1,2,3,4)
R=(0,1,2,3,4)
y= m.addVars(n,5, name="y", vtype=GRB.BINARY)
yy= m.addVars(n,5*n, name="yy", vtype=GRB.BINARY)

if (y[i,r]+y[j,r]==2): yy[i,j+5*r]=1 for i in I for j in I for r in R
```

If both y variables are 1, i want yy to be 1 aswell, 0 in all other cases.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to write programming logic or optimization model logic?

Comment: Should be optimization model logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
if y[i,r]+y[j,r] == 2:
    for i in I:
        for j in I:
            for r in R:
                yy[i,j+5*r]=1
else:
    yy[i,j+5*r]=0
```

I haven't tried as I am not able to get your `m.addVars`. If I am not wrong this is something to do with filtering of an image?^_^

Comment: m.addVars adds variables to the optimisation model.
Tried your solution, but it gives me an NameError: r is not defined.

Comment: Oh man I am so stupid, I did not know Python only works if you have proper indentations.


Tried your solution and it gave me the needed error code for me to realise that, thanks a lot!